# How to use apoc.periodic.repeat properly?

Tags: neo4j

I am pretty new to Neo4j. I'm trying to update a graph with apoc.periodic.repeat, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is a mock example:

- I created nodes for few countries with MERGE (co:Country {id: #, capital: "capital city"})
- Then I created cities with MATCH (co:Country) MERGE (c:City {name: co.capital })

I created more countries than cities to test apoc.periodic.repeat. Then I ran the following:

CALL apoc.periodic.repeat("create-cities",
"MATCH (co:Country) MERGE (c:City {name: co.capital})", 1)

This doesn't create new nodes with City label. Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAzzX.png). I'm not sure why it says "false" under done. Can someone please explain why this is not producing the expected outcome? Is there another way to achieve the desired outcome?

EDIT: It turned out that I was using it correctly. I just had some apoc.periodic.iterate jobs running in the background that, I guess, prevented this job from running or perhaps delayed it. I ran :queries and killed all the existing jobs then this job ran as expected.

Comment: Why do you expect new city nodes when you already created all the city nodes before?

Comment: I created more countries than cities, so new city nodes should be created

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the use of [`apoc.trigger.add`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.trigger/apoc.trigger.add/).

You first need to enable triggers in apoc.conf file:
`apoc.trigger.enabled=true`

Then you can create the trigger as below.

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
  'create-cities',
  'UNWIND [co IN $createdNodes WHERE id(co) > 0 AND co:Country] AS co
  MERGE (c:City {name: co.capital})',
  {}
);
```

For testing, the following query should trigger the creation of a Vluatchuk :City node.

```
MERGE (co:Country {id: "Elbonia", capital: "Vluatchuk"})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would this work for periodic updates? I'm going to stream big data, so I would like to use a method that would run in the background to periodically update the graphs I have.

Comment: Ok. If I get it right, you want cities to be created repeatedly by batches.
Actually I've just tested your code with apoc.periodic.repeat and it works well for me.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure why it's not working for me! Can you please tell me which version of Neo4j you have? Do you get "true" under done in the result table?

Comment: I actually found out why it wasn't running. I ran :queries and found that there were multiple jobs running in the background and I guess they prevented this one from running. After I killed all the jobs, this one ran as expected :)